# Virtue-mart products-categories move to WooCommerce

Tags: php, migration, joomla1.5, virtuemart, wordpress-4.9

Do you know any possible way to move/migrate the products from Virtuemart to Woocommerce? without using any paid plugins.

**Version Details**

From VirtueMart Version : 1.1.9 (Joomla 1.5.26)

To WooCommerce Version: 3.4.5 (Wordpress 4.9.8)

Looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: Writing your own migration scripts. Have you tried that?

Comment: no please share if you have..thanks!!

Comment: Try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextcart-woocommerce-migration/. It's offerred by [Next-Cart](https://next-cart.com/) and free.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this plugin link. Before you have to check the wordpress version and plugin version, but you try to use this plugin.

**Plugin Link -** https://wordpress.org/plugins/cart2cart-virtuemart-to-woocommerce-migration/

Thanks!

Comment: I already use this plugins but its generate fatal error: Call to undefined function Cart2cart

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function Cart2cart\curl_init() in /var/www/html/sw-tt-griprite/wp-content/plugins/cart2cart-virtuemart-to-woocommerce-migration/class/Api.php on line 34

Comment: If you're on Windows: Go to your php.ini file and remove the ; mark from the beginning of the following line: ;extension=php_curl.dll ..... After you have saved the file you must restart your HTTP server software (e.g. Apache) before this can take effect.

Comment: Hey this is paid plugin i want to use free plugin so please tell me if you have another idea to move product data from virtuemart to wocommerce.